# Combine commands in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, variables

I've used windows cmd shell for years but I've decided to switch to powershell.

My command in cmd shell to make a backup of a file adding the date and time:

```
copy /-Y "D:\MyFiles\workat.txt" d:\bkp_workat_'. strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M", getftime('D:\MyFiles\workat.txt')) .'.txt'
```

`workat.txt --> bkp_workat_2019-02-14_17-52.txt`

The same command in powershell:

```
$RCTime = (ls D:\MyFiles\workat.txt).LastWriteTime 
$myDate = $RCTime.ToString('yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm') 
Copy-Item D:\MyFiles\workat.txt -destination "D:\MyFiles\workat_$myDate.txt"
```

This works fine but I need to combine the 3 commands in a single command.

This is what I've done:

```
$RCTime = (ls D:\MyFiles\workat.txt).LastWriteTime | $myDate = $RCTime.ToString('yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm') | Copy-Item D:\MyFiles\workat.txt -destination "D:\MyFiles\workat_$myDate.txt"
```

This gives an error: `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline`

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `;` for daisy-chaining independent statements. Use the pipe (`|`) for connecting the output of one command to the input of another.

You can also daisy-chain dot-access to properties and methods:

```
(ls D:\MyFiles\workat.txt).LastWriteTime.ToString('yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm')
```

However, the most PoSh translation of your original commands would probably look somewhat like this:

```
Get-Item 'D:\MyFiles\workat.txt' |
    Copy-Item -Destination { 'D:\MyFiles\workat_{0:yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.txt' -f $_.LastWriteTime }
```

or this:

```
Get-Item 'D:\MyFiles\workat.txt' |
    Copy-Item -Destination { Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($_.BaseName + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('_yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm') + $_.Extension }
```

`Get-Item` produces a `FileInfo` object from the given path and passes that to `Copy-Item` via the pipeline. Since `Copy-Item` can read input from the pipeline you don't need to specify the source (as that comes from the pipeline), just the destination. And since you're reading from the pipeline you can use the current object variable `$_` to access properties of the source object (note: you need a scriptblock, i.e. the curly brackets around the expression, for that to work).

The first example is using the format operator `-f` for inserting the date into the path string, the second example is using the `Join-Path` cmdlet and string concatenation for building the destination path from various properties of the input object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$RCTime = (ls C:\MyFiles\workat.txt).LastWriteTime;$myDate = $RCTime.ToString('yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm') | Copy-Item D:\MyFiles\workat.txt -destination "C:\MyFiles\workat_$myDate.txt"
```

You're trying to pipe another variable to another variable. Hence why you're getting the error. And just curious, why are you wanting to structure it all on one line? It's good practice to do it like so:

```
$RCTime = (ls C:\MyFiles\workat.txt).LastWriteTime
$myDate = $RCTime.ToString('yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm')
Copy-Item D:\MyFiles\workat.txt -destination "C:\MyFiles\workat_$myDate.txt"
```

Comment: Still an error  --> Copy-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Comment: Try: $RCTime = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "C:\MyFiles\workat.txt" -Name LastWriteTime

Answer (score 1):

() are a way to embed the results of one command into a call to another command.   You were basically doing this with the set of the $RCTime

```
Copy-Item D:\MyFiles\workat.txt -destination "D:\MyFiles\workat_$((ls D:\MyFiles\workat.txt).LastWriteTime.ToString('yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm')).txt"
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. It still gives an error --> Copy-Item : The given path's format is not supported.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item D:\MyFiles\workat.txt -destination "D:\MyFiles\workat_$(ls  ...

Comment: I was missing a set of () I copied the wrong line that tested :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pipelines expect explicit data depending on the CMDLET being called. In your example, you are setting variables equal to CMDLETs and then trying to pipe that to the next command. You can really only have one variable set per line but if you switch out the pipes for semicolons, it should work, but not best practice.

If you want to do a true one liner, you need to nest your calls and it would look something like this.

```
Copy-Item D:\MyFiles\workat.txt -destination "D:\MyFiles\workat_$($(Get-ChildItem D:\MyFiles\workat.txt).LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm")).txt"
```